# Determine the /category/ in the URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, indexof

I have a need to include (through Javascript) different content depending on the major category captured from the url.

The website is laid out like so:

http://example.com/Category/Arts/Other/Sub/Categories/

http://example.com/Category/News/Other/Sub/Categories/

http://example.com/Category/Sports/Other/Sub/Categories/

http://example.com/Category/Business_And_Finance/Other/Sub/Categories/

The different major categories above are:

**Arts, News, Sports, and Business_And_Finance**

What is the best way to accomplish this in javascript.
What I need may look something like the following,

```
if (category = Arts) {
    alert("Arts");
}else if (category = News) {
    alert("News");
}...
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the location.href then do a switch on the appropriate variable. So, for example:

```
var url = document.location.href,
    split = url.split("/");

/*
  Split will resemble something like this:
  ["http:", "", "example.com", "Category", "Arts", "Other", "Sub", "Categories", ""]

  So, you'll find the bit you're interested in at the 4th element in the array
*/
switch(split[4]){
  case "Arts":
    alert("I do say old chap");
    break;

  case "News":
    alert("Anything interesting on?");
    break;

  default:
    alert("I have no idea what page you're on :O!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I needed. And thanks to all those who answered below. Most answers seem to use the same `url.split` idea. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the current url like this

```
document.location.href
```

you could do a

```
if (    document.location.href.indexOf("categoryYouWant")>-1){
     //whatever you want
}
```

but you should do a regular expression

```
category=document.location.href.match(/example\.com\/(\w+)\//i)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;

var category = url.split('Category/')[1].split('/')[0];

if (category === 'Arts') {
    alert("Arts");
}else if (category === 'News') {
    alert("News");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function determine(url)
        {
           var myArray = url.split('/'); 
           if(myArray[4] == "News")
           alert(myArray[4]);

        }

        </script>
    </head> 

    <body> 

        <div>       
            <a href="" onclick="determine('http://example.com/Category/News/Other/Sub/Categories/')">http://example.com/Category/News/Other/Sub/Categories/</a>       
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Saludos ;)